# Obtaining ENUM description in Java based on value

Tags: java, spring, jpa, enums

I'm new to ENUMs so I want to make sure I'm doing all of this right before I perform a little surgery on my models.  My ENUM has a shorter string that's stored in the database known as the `name`, and a `description` which is what the user sees.  My objective is to get the description for a content object to show on the page.

Of course

```
<td valign='top'><strong>Paperless:</strong> ${content.getPaperless()}</td>
```

won't do it because that'll only show `EDELIVERY_REQUIRED`.  How do I need to adjust this to make it function properly?

My edit page works great:

```
    <td valign='top'>
        <strong>Go Paperless Messaging</strong><br/>
        <form:select path="paperless">
            <form:options items="${paperlessEnumValues}" itemValue="name" itemLabel="description"/>
        </form:select>
    </td>
```

**My enum:**

```
public enum Paperless {
    NONE(null, ""),
    EDELIVERY_RECOMMENDED("EDELIVERY_RECOMMENDED", "Recommend eDelivery"),
    EDELIVERY_REQUIRED("EDELIVERY_REQUIRED", "Require eDelivery"),
    EDELIVERY_REQUIRED_JUSTIFICATION("EDELIVERY_REQUIRED_JUSTIFICATION", "Require eDelivery w/out justification");

    private String name;
    private String description;
    Paperless(String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }
}
```

**My Model**

```
public class Content implements Serializable {
...

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "paperless")
    private String paperless;
...
    public String getPaperless() {
        return paperless;
    }

    public void setPaperless(String paperless) {
        this.paperless = paperless;
    }
```

**My content service**

```
private List<Content> findContentEntities(boolean all, int maxResults, int firstResult) {
    try {
        CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(Content.class));
        Query q = em.createQuery(cq);
        if (!all) {
            q.setMaxResults(maxResults);
            q.setFirstResult(firstResult);
        }
        return q.getResultList();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Map `private Paperless paperless` in your entity, rather than a String. JPA supports enum mapping
2. Use `${content.paperless.description}`

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I think JPA map enum with the name of the enum value not an attribute like he want

Comment: as far as I understood, he wants to map the enum name. That's why the name is showing in the jsp.

Comment: Unfortunately we're having trouble getting JPA to work properly on saving our data so right now we're writing the saving portion of it manually.

Comment: I've made the change to use a `Paperless` object instead of a string, but it throws a `Exception Description: The object [EDELIVERY_REQUIRED], of class [class java.lang.String], from mapping [org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[paperless-->content.paperless]] with descriptor [RelationalDescriptor(com.mysite.cmt.model.Content --> [DatabaseTable(content)])], could not be converted to [class java.lang.Integer].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "EDELIVERY_REQUIRED"` in my Content Service which I've included above.